# Error message: Value of type 'Int' has no member 'frame'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm coding along with a tutorial on making a puzzle game in swift, and I keep getting this error message on line 16

> Value of type **'Int'** has no member **'frame'**.

I tried checking other stack overflow threads and it would seem that this perhaps has something to do with the fact that I'm using Swift 4? If that is the case, how do I correct it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var gameView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    var gameViewWidth: Int!
    var blockWidth: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        gameViewWidth = Int( gameViewWidth.frame.size.width )
        blockWidth = gameViewWidth / 4

        let blockFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        let block: UILabel = UILabel(frame: blockFrame)
        block.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        gameView.addSubview(block)
    }

    @IBAction func resetAction(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to correction         gameViewWidth = Int( gameViewWidth.frame.size.width ) into         gameViewWidth = Int( gameView.frame.size.width ), you should avoid using Implicitly unwrapped for your var. Just declare as var gameViewWidth = 0, it will be set to the right value later, in viewWillLayoutSubviews()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
gameViewWidth = Int( gameViewWidth.frame.size.width )
```

needs to be:

```
gameViewWidth = Int( gameView.frame.size.width )
```

It is the width of `gameView` that you want. Or maybe just `view`. It's not 100% clear which view you want the width of.

Either way, `viewDidLoad` is not a good place for that code since the size of the view isn't finalized yet. It's too soon.

Code that depends on the size of a view should be in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` since a view's size can change over time (such as when a device is rotated or a user takes a phone call and switched back to your app while on the call, etc.).